# How to plot on multiple subplots inside a for loop

Tags: python, python-3.x

So my sample DF is something like this:

```py
data = pd.DataFrame({
    'ID':[1,1,2,2,2],
    'gender':['male', 'female', 'male', 'female', 'female'],
    'Dependents':['yes', 'no', 'yes', 'no', 'yes'],
    'PhoneService': ['yes', 'no', 'yes', 'no', 'yes'],
    'InternetService':['yes', 'no', 'yes', 'no', 'yes'] 
    'Churn':['yes', 'no', 'yes', 'no', 'yes']
})
```

There are around 15 other columns within similar yes/no values.

I want to plot stacked bars for each of my columns with yes/no values on x-axis against the Churn column on y-axis showing the count of Yes/No for each category on the x-axis.

I can plot a single stacked bar chart like this:

```
gender_plot = data.groupby(['gender', 'Churn']).size().reset_index().pivot(columns='Churn', index='gender', values=0)
gender_plot.plot.bar(stacked=True)
```

I can also use a for loop to iterate over all the columns required to be plotted like this:

```
columns_to_visualise = ['gender', 'Partner', 'Dependents', 'PhoneService', 'MultipleLines', 'InternetService', 'OnlineSecurity', 'OnlineBackup', 
                        'DeviceProtection', 'TechSupport', 'StreamingTV', 'StreamingMovies', 'Contract', 'PaperlessBilling', 'PaymentMethod', 'SeniorCitizen']

for column in columns_to_visualise:
    plot_data = data.groupby([column, 'Churn']).size().reset_index().pivot(columns='Churn', index=column, values=0)
    plot_data.plot.bar(stacked=True, rot = 45)

plt.show()
```

Obviously the output from the above for loop results in all bar charts to be plotted on separate axes.

I tried to plot them on subplots using help from several previous SO posts but none helped me

How can I update my code to plot these 16 stacked bar charts as subplots in a single 4x4 figure?

Thanks